# how to make text BOLD and Red

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I make the below exception return BOLD and text font RED? The wordings of "return "***WMI Error***";"

This is used later in the code for returning WMI parameters in a textbox...as shown below:

```
 private static string GetMOValue(ManagementObject mo, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                object result = mo[name];
                return result == null ? "" : result.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "***WMI Error***";
            }
        }

        private void cmbHdd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //try
            //{
                ManagementObjectSearcher mosDisks = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Model = '" + cmbHdd.SelectedItem + "'");
                foreach (ManagementObject moDisk in mosDisks.Get())
                {
                    //try
                    //{
                    txtSystemName.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "systemname");
                    txtType.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "MediaType");
                    txtModel.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "Model");
                    txtFirmware.Text = GetMOValue(moDisk, "FirmwareRevision");
.....
```

Comment: There is no concept of formatting (just encoding) in a standard string, what you are referring to is entirely a UI concern and will depend on what control you intend to use to show the data. If you are using a basic WinForms text box, then the Font can be made bold and the ForeColor can be made red. Also, it's not a great idea to catch all exceptions without handling them properly.

Comment: The exception itself doesn't have a font; it's the place where it it displayed to the user that you must go and change the font.

Comment: ok - makes sense. It was more a case of thinking if the "WMI Error" string that is returned in the textbox can be highlighted...

Comment: @lara400 Then you'd need something like an RTF control to highlight a specific portion of text - a standard textbox (in WinForms) formats the entire content, not just a portion.

Comment: ok thanks for that Adam...flippin heck the mark down brigade are in town I see :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox is not a web browser. It supports showing text with a single font - no decorations, colors, etc. You can change a font for the textbox in runtime.

You could handle the `TextChanged` event of the textbox to achieve this, but this is not an example of nice code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Font defaultFont = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;

  if(textBox1.Text.StartsWith("**") && textBox1.Text.EndsWith("**"))
  {
    textBox1.Font = new Font(defaultFont.FontFamily, defaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
    textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    // note: can't change text here as it will recursively trigger this handler
  }
  else
  {
    textBox1.Font = defaultFont;
    textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
  }
}
```

A better approach would be to have a simple method which will set the text and textbox attributes.

the soapbox: Please note that I consider this form of checking the text for ** characters to see if it is an error, extremely ugly and unreliable. What you should do is have something like

```
Font defaultFont = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
try
{ 
   textBox1.Text = GetMOValue(...);
   textBox1.Font = defaultFont;
   textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
   textBox1.Text = "ERROR";
   textBox1.Font = new Font(defaultFont.FontFamily, defaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
   textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
// the Font and ForeColor properties are repeatedly set in case that previous
// try had the different result (e.g. previous => error, current => OK, so 
// we need to reset the attributes of textbox
```

You can use RichTextBox, WebBrowser or some custom drawn control to support fancier formatting.

Comment: this is really good - let me see if I can implement this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No it is not good, actually :) I have added some notes, please see the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the method return exception or not, if yes, change set font and color of textbox dynamically:

```
textBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;    
textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void btnBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.rtxText.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(rtxText.Font.FontFamily,Convert.ToInt16(nudFontSize.Value), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ^ this.rtxText.SelectionFont.Style);
    }

    //ITALICS CODING
    private void btnItalics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.rtxText.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(rtxText.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt16(nudFontSize.Value), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic ^ this.rtxText.SelectionFont.Style);
    }

    //UNDERLINE CODING
    private void btnUnderline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.rtxText.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(rtxText.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt16(nudFontSize.Value), System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline ^ this.rtxText.SelectionFont.Style);
    }
```